# How can I monitor in real time the changes to the browser's WM_NAME

Tags: x11, monitoring, wmctrl

I need to check how the browser's WM_NAME (let's say google-chrome) is changing in real time.

How can I do that ?

Comment: Could you explain in what setting you need ot?

Comment: I need this for i3wm since I suspect that initial title is different that actual one, so I can't use layout's "swallow" functionality properly.

Answer (score 3):

WM_CLASS is never changing. It's always the same.
I think you're trying to catch the `VISIBLE_NAME`.

That can be done with `xprop`:

```
xprop -spy -id 0x01a00092 _NET_WM_VISIBLE_NAME
_NET_WM_VISIBLE_NAME(UTF8_STRING) = "x11 - How can I monitor in real time the changes to the browsers WM_CLASS - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange ::: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/349872/how-can-i-monitor-in-real-time-the-changes-to-the-browsers-wm-class - Pale Moon"
_NET_WM_VISIBLE_NAME(UTF8_STRING) = "Newest Unanswered Questions - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange ::: http://unix.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=newest - Pale Moon"
_NET_WM_VISIBLE_NAME(UTF8_STRING) = "x11 - How can I monitor in real time the changes to the browsers WM_CLASS - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange ::: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/349872/how-can-i-monitor-in-real-time-the-changes-to-the-browsers-wm-class - Pale Moon"
```

`-id xxx` is the window id of the target window you want to monitor.

Comment: How do I get the "id" of a window ? I need to start browser and immediately run the "monitor" command after that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `xtrace` to monitor changes in window properties. In Debian, `xtrace` can be installed using `sudo apt-get install xtrace`.

Example usage: to monitor how the Chromium web browser is changing its `WM_NAME` property, first close all Chromium windows, then run `xtrace -n -- chromium | awk '/ChangeProperty/ && /"WM_NAME"/'`. You should then see some output similar to this:

```
001:<:00aa: 32: Request(18): ChangeProperty mode=Replace(0x00) window=0x03200001 property=0x27("WM_NAME") type=0x1f("STRING") data='chromium'
000:<:0101: 24: Request(18): ChangeProperty mode=Replace(0x00) window=0x02400002 property=0x27("WM_NAME") type=0x15d("UTF8_STRING") data=;
000:<:010c: 44: Request(18): ChangeProperty mode=Replace(0x00) window=0x02400002 property=0x27("WM_NAME") type=0x15d("UTF8_STRING") data=0x55,0x6e,0x74,0x69,0x74,0x6c,0x65,0x64,0x20,0x2d,0x20,0x43,0x68,0x72,0x6f,0x6d,0x69,0x75,0x6d;
000:<:0117: 44: Request(18): ChangeProperty mode=Replace(0x00) window=0x02400002 property=0x27("WM_NAME") type=0x15d("UTF8_STRING") data=0x4e,0x65,0x77,0x20,0x54,0x61,0x62,0x20,0x2d,0x20,0x43,0x68,0x72,0x6f,0x6d,0x69,0x75,0x6d;
```

This means that the `WM_NAME` property changed from "chromium" to "" to "Untitled - Chromium" to "New Tab - Chromium".

Reference: https://www.x.org/wiki/guide/debugging/